# How to log in office 365 with Rest API

Tags: rest, api, oauth, office365

I'm have a problem, in the company where I Job, we need create a unique access to all applications with Office 365, but is an institution educative with a domain own ***"@umm.edu.gt"*** for example, we used the portal.office.com, I can access to *login.live.com* with REST API, this with **https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf** but only with hotmail account, it's not possible with this domain own.

My question is specific, exist something as **oauth20_authorize.srf** for account with domain own?, Or have any opinion or suggestion for this problem.

Comment: This problem is not solved with REST API, nor with a srt link, to solve it I had to do a mixture of technologies, using powershell, C # and sql server, this architecture to recover data, verify authentication and deploy to the web any Doubt me can consult.